# Script using find to count lines of code

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a shell script that will count the number of lines of code in one folder.

I got this:

```
h=find . -type f -name \*.[h]* -print0 | xargs -0 cat | wc -l
m=find . -type f -name \*.[m]* -print0 | xargs -0 cat | wc -l

expr $m + $h
```

But when I'm trying to run it I get this:

```
lines-of-code: line 6: .: -t: invalid option
.: usage: . filename [arguments]
   0
lines-of-code: line 7: .: -t: invalid option
.: usage: . filename [arguments]
   0
+
```

I know I have to do something to make it run on the specific folder I'm in. Is this even possible?

Comment: I feel compelled to mention that counting lines of code is not a viable metric.

Comment: no im aware of that. i just want to be able to know how much -ish code ive written

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DDIYS (don't to it your self)  Use [cloc](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) instead. Excelent tool written in perl that does the counting for you as well as a other things. It recognizes more than 80 languages.

Example output:

```
prompt> cloc perl-5.10.0.tar.gz
    4076 text files.
    3883 unique files.                                          
    1521 files ignored.

http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.50  T=12.0 s (209.2 files/s, 70472.1 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Perl                          2052         110356         130018         292281
C                              135          18718          22862         140483
C/C++ Header                   147           7650          12093          44042
Bourne Shell                   116           3402           5789          36882
Lisp                             1            684           2242           7515
make                             7            498            473           2044
C++                             10            312            277           2000
XML                             26            231              0           1972
yacc                             2            128             97           1549
YAML                             2              2              0            489
DOS Batch                       11             85             50            322
HTML                             1             19              2             98
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                          2510         142085         173903         529677
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Quote the commands like:

```
h=$(find . -type f -name *.[h]* -print0 | xargs -0 cat | wc -l)
```

Please also have a look at [sloccount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/) for counting lines of code. You can install it on debian/ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install sloccount`

Answer (score 1):

For this specific problem, I have a different solution:

```
find . -type f -print0 | wc --files0-from=-
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it works!

```
h=$(find . -type f -name \*.[h]* -print0 | xargs -0 cat | wc -l)
m=$(find . -type f -name \*.[m]* -print0 | xargs -0 cat | wc -l)

expr $m + $h
```

Answer (score 0):

May be I misunderstood the question, but does this work for you?

```
wc -l *.[mh]*
```